# Openshift cluster(v4.6) using crc has empty operators hub

Tags: openshift, redhat-containers, 3scale

I have downloaded code ready containers on windows for installing my openshift cluster. I need to deploy 3scale on it using the operator from operators hub but the operators hub page is empty.
Digging deeper I found that a few pods on the cluster are not running and show a state "ImagePullBackOff"
I deleted the pods in order to get them restarted but the error wont go away. I checked the event logs and all the screenshotted images are attached.
[Pods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCotZ.png) [Terminal logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRC3E.png)
This is an error that I keep on getting when I start my cluster. Sometimes it comes up sometimes it starts normally but maybe this has something to do with it.
[Quay.io Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuINC.png)
This is my fist time making a deployment on openshift cluster and setting up my cluster environment. So far I am not able to resolve the issue even after deleting and restarting the cluster.

Comment: This sounds like it could be a proxy issue. Looking at your screenshot, it's timing out trying to access the registry. Are you running behind a proxy? Have you checked the [proxy section in the documentation](https://code-ready.github.io/crc/#starting-codeready-containers-behind-proxy_gsg)?

Comment: No I'm not using any proxy server